# How to generate a JSON file from aq PHP database?

Tags: php, json

I have an online PHP/mySQL database from which I need an android app to be populated with data. How do I create a JSON file from the PHP/mySQL database?

Answer (score 1):

just select what you need from your DB, put it in `$array`
and use

```
string json_encode ( mixed $value [, int $options = 0 [, int $depth = 512 ]] )
```

for example:

```
$json = json_encode($array)
```

and then put it in the file with:

```
int file_put_contents ( string $filename , mixed $data [, int $flags = 0 [, resource $context ]] )
```

example:

```
file_put_contents('file.json', $json)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really understood that and I think that could help out. Could you please tell me what the problem in this code is?

Comment: try
{ $con = mysql_connect("localhost","muhit","", "canteendb");
 mysql_select_db("canteendb", $con);
 $returnArray = array();
 $sql = "SELECT itemName, pricePerUnit,
         unit, restaurantID, category
         FROM Item WHERE 1 ";
 $query = mysql_query($sql);
 while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {    
  $returnArray[] = $rs;     }
$fp = fopen('C:/Users/Ishtiaq/Downloads/Compressed/Codes/json/file4.json', 'w+');
file_put_contents('C:/Users/Ishtiaq/Downloads/Compressed/Codes/json/file4.json', $json)
fwrite($fp, json_encode($returnArray));
fclose($fp);
 mysql_close($con);
}

Answer (score 0):

Create an php file and access the database. 
With

```
json_encode($array)
```

you can produce a json representative from your array. Depending on your planned App you can just echo the json or use some kind of soap webservice

Answer (score 0):

Just use a php command to encode anything in json. Here is the php command which lets you to encode anything in json.

```
json_encode($text)
```

After encoding just put file_get_contents() function in php to put it in a .json file

Answer (score 0):

In order to have `JSON` format of your data in the database:

1. Fetch the data from the database using PHP and store them as an array called `$data`
2. Convert the the array `$data` to `JSON`, use `echo json_encode($data);`to have them printed in JSON format